# how to get totalDistance of HKWorkout

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

At the moment I am working on a running app for the iPhone.

One issue that I have is, that I am building the `HKWorkout` using the `HKWorkoutBuilder` according to [Apples Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutbuilder).

But I am not able to associate the `totalDistance` with the workout – mentioned [here in the Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/adding_samples_to_a_workout). `totalDistance` is `nil` when I try to read it from the workout – no surprise because I didnt set it. As I understand the `HKWorkoutBuilder` provides no way to add the `totalDistance`.

I think I miss something here.

Comment: You add it to the workout sample you provide https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout

Comment: Look at [Creating a workout](https://developer.apple.com/documentatView1ion/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/creating_a_workout_route) in the documentation

Comment: @Paulw11 thats not the way I build the Workouts (with HKWorkoutBuilder). [See my links above](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutbuilder).
@loremipsum [yes that is what I do](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/creating_a_workout_route). But there is no way to save the `totalDistance` attribute to the Workout. I cant image that this is the way its supposed to be – to sum up all locations from the route. Even in the Health App is a weird blank spot on each workout – where I think the distance should be shown.

Comment: It is your responsibility to track the total distance as the workout is running, say by accumulating the distance between the location updates you add to the route. You then provide this distance when you create the `HKWorkout` as I said above. The route you have built is then associated with this workout and you save it to the HealthKit store.

Comment: You dont checked the links I provided. The `HKWorkout` doesnt get created by me, but by the `HKWorkoutBuilder` there is no way to manually add the distance ;-)

Comment: Yep, same issue @gustav. The workout is returned by the builder in a callback, but how do we update the total distance? I am adding the samples but my samples are not included in the total distance computed by Health Kit (with its own samples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your distance samples to `HKWorkoutBuilder` using its [addSamples](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutbuilder/2962911-addsamples?language=objc) method. The total distance will be calculated for you based on the samples you add. e.g you can add samples of type `HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning` to the workout and it should populate `totalDistance`.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I can see the entry in the health app in the detail view for the workout.. (Distance Walking Running) but I can not get it through `HKWorkout.totalDistance`. Even in the health app it shows a blank spot in the overview. I do miss something here...

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that I was not adding the distance samples with a completion handler – and did not waited for completition until I called `finishWorkout()` on the builder. I think that messed up the workout somehow.